# init with UIButtonTypeCustom option in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

```
UIButton * test=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 49, 49)];

test.buttonType= UIButtonTypeCustom;
```

**-> assinging to property with  'readonly'** **attribute not a allow

why? how??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the class method

```
+ buttonWithType:
```

to create the button. After that, set the frame.

From the [UIButton Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html):

> **buttonType**
>
> The button type. (read-only)
>
> `@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIButtonType buttonType`

This means that you cannot change the `buttonType` once the button as been created.

For example, you can do

```
UIButton *test = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
test.frame = CGRectMake(30, 30, 49, 49);
```